# How can request.method == None in Django

Tags: python, django, httprequest

I am trying to figure out this issue related to Django from https://github.com/miki725/Django-jQuery-File-Uploader-Integration-demo/issues/1

Under what conditions can `request.method == None` in Django?

Comment: Aside: remember when you're checking for `None` to use `is` rather than `==` as it's more particular.

Comment: Thank you. I always forget to do that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `request.method` is never `None` in real use, but for your particular case, you're looking at the wrong thing.

## Generic `HttpRequest`

`django/http/__init__.py`:

```
class HttpRequest(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.method = None
        ...
```

When a plain `HttpRequest` is instantiated, its method is `None`. But then, `WSGIRequest` and `ModPythonRequest` don't call `HttpRequest.__init__` ever.

## Requests through `mod_wsgi`

`django/core/handlers/wsgi.py`:

```
class WSGIRequest(http.HttpRequest):
    ...
    def __init__(self, environ):
        ...
        self.method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD'].upper()
        ...
```

The summary of this is that for mod_wsgi, `request.method` will *never* be `None`. If in some warped way you managed to get `environ['REQUEST_METHOD']` not being defined or being `None`, the request would fail.

## Requests through `mod_python`

`django/core/handlers/modpython.py`:

```
class ModPythonRequest(http.HttpRequest):
    ...
    def _get_method(self):
        return self.META['REQUEST_METHOD'].upper()
    ...
    method = property(_get_method)
```

Same remarks as with `WSGIRequest` apply. Can't ever be `None`.

## Test client

`django.test.client.RequestFactory.request` instantiates a `WSGIRequest` and is called every time with `REQUEST_METHOD` defined in the `environ` as an uppercase string, as it should be.

---

**Summary:**

```
assert request.method is not None
```

You're looking for the error in the wrong place. In this case, `request.method == 'POST'`. It's failing when `request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '') is None`. The reason for this is that the `Content-Type` header isn't being sent by the client in the request (don't ask me why, I'm not familiar with that stuff).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to happen via AJAX, specifically calling jQuery's $.ajax function (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with "POST" type but no data:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/something",
    });
```